# the location of the folders changed but nothing works now

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I moved the images and js into their own folders, typed "..\folder_name\name.jpg" in the PHP file but those which I used them in the background doesn't appear on the screen. And the whole screen except the texts is just white :-/
I type w3-blue on a container but it is just white. the links in the head are fine. the only thing I changed was the folders and the location of the folders in the PHP file.

```
.image-container-ebook {
  background-image: url("..\project\image\20.png");
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```
<script src="..\project\js\mysearch.js"></script>
```

This little code was working before. Do I have to add something more? and please also help me out with a javascript and PHP files. There is a modal I use to open for Login written with PHP but when I open it now, it says that it can not find a file but the location is fine.
[this is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BBpl.jpg)

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Personally, I try to avoid using relative paths and stick to absolute paths. For instance, using `/apps/project/js/` instead of  `../project/js/`.

Comment: no the only error i get is from the php file "login" it says it cannot find the path
and i tried the absolut path but still everything is white and the images are gone

Comment: Shouldn't those backslashes be forward slashes?

Comment: oh :D it worked
but if you check the photo which i uploaded, i used back slashes.
great, but still javascript is not working